# stdout escaped query and stdin collision in C program (no ncurses)

Tags: c, escaping, printf, stdout, stdin

I'm writing a small cli program without ncurses, and i am facing a problem.
I use an escape sequence to query the cursor position, this works properly when there is no or low input by user, but when user does high input frequency this pollute my query response.

I use read for handle user input like that :

```
read(0, &c, sizeof(c))
```

I use printf/scanf for handle escape sequence query like that :

```
printf("\033[6n");
scanf("\033[%d;%dR", y, x);
```

To clear out the problem, i try to get cursor position after each read. When i keep pushing a key (exemple "z") i receive some z between the printf and scanf so scanf fail.
I expected that user input be blocked or buffered during query but not :(.

After query i can go to search the sequence on stdin stream before scanf and buffer inputs but is quite heavy and it's not 100% sure.

Is there a simple solution to get around this problem ?
(ensure the order, blocking user input before query, etc...)

**Edit at 2014-07-01 21:21 :**

I create a little sample to bring out the problem.
There is no problem with standard key, but UP key, or HOME key pollute printf/scanf query sequence...

```
// Build gcc -o test main.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

char getch();
void get_cursor_pos(int* x, int* y);
void reset_terminal_mode();

struct termios g_termios;

int main(int arc, char** argv)
{
    char c;
    int x,y;
    struct termios new_termios; 
    printf("TEST STDOUT/STDIN QUERY\n");

    // Setting raw terminal
    printf("Setting raw terminal mode...\n");
    tcgetattr(0, &g_termios);
    memcpy(&new_termios, &g_termios, sizeof(struct termios));
    atexit(reset_terminal_mode);
    cfmakeraw(&new_termios);            
    new_termios.c_oflag |= OPOST|ONLCR;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_termios);

    // Main loop
    printf("Starting main loop...\n");
    printf("(Press [=] to abort)\n");
    do{
        c=getch();
    printf("0x%02X",c); 
    get_cursor_pos(&x,&y);
    printf("<%dx%d> ",x,y);         
    }while(c!='=');

    // End loop
    printf("\nEnd\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char getch()
{
    char c;
    read(0, &c, sizeof(c));
    return c;
}

void get_cursor_pos(int* x, int* y)
{
    *x=0; 
    *y=0;
    printf("\033[6n");
    scanf("\033[%d;%dR", y, x);
}

void reset_terminal_mode()
{
    printf("Reset terminal mode...\n");
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &g_termios);
}
```

Can you explain me what append ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The user of your programme is supposed to input escape sequences? That seems like you have some misconception about what VT100 escape sequences are for…

Comment: That happens, when you hit function keys, or numeric keypad in certain modes.  This sounds like a design error.  When I wrote ncurses applications, in general it was only within small fields for data entry where user input was echoed.  Rest were Menu/type keys & navigation on screen, where BECAUSE the application knows where they're going, no QUERY required, it just sets the cursor to a position, on screen draw (or by redraw if screen messed up, when user do CNTL-L)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `getch()`, as written, to capture `Home` or `Arrow` keys, because the key-codes are **multi-byte** codes.  You will have to alter your `getch()` function to handle both single and multi-byte input to capture keys that use multi-byte codes. See [**Unicode in C/C++**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) for a fairly thorough explanation and examples of routines to handle multi-byte input.

Comment: Thanks you David, this is so evident... i feel a bit silly... i left a char in stdin, so first response of query is this char... many thanks to take your time to explain me.